# Porque obtengo undefined de mi variable en la vista?

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

Estoy obteniendo undefined en mi vista por una variable de un metodo del controlador y nose porque porque lo estoy pasando correctamente.

Este es mi metodo:

```
public function detail($id){
    $detailData = Product::find($id);
    $detailData['ptypes'] = Ptype::all();
    $detailData['brands'] = Brand::all();
    $detailData['models'] = ModelP::all();

    return view('backend.products.detail', $detailData);
}
```

Y esta es mi ruta:

```
Route::get('/detail/{id}','Backend\ProductController@detail')->name('products.detail');
```

El error esta aca en la vista:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
                      <label for="ptype">Tipo de producto</label>
                      <input type="text" name="ptype" value="{{ $detailData->ptype }}" class="form-control" readonly>
                  </div>
```

Me dice que $detailData es undefined. Nose porque, ya como mostre en el metodo, estoy pasando la variable. Tambien trate pasandola usando compact o pasandola en un array y el error persiste. Limpie el cache, la config y sigue todo igual.

Comment: value="{{ $detailData->ptype }}" ptype no existe, tu lo declarastes como ptypes (solo falta la s)

Comment: @HeynerMartinez Pero es $detailData la que devuelve undefined, no ptype

Comment: ya me percaté del problema, return view('backend.products.detail', $detailData); tienes que enviar a la vista la variable ya sea de estas dos formas. return view('backend.products.detail', compact(detailData)); o bien return view('backend.products.detail', ['detailData'=>$detailData]);

Comment: Creo que si lees bien el problema que tengo en mi pregunta veras que puse que ya pase la variable a través del metodo compact, y tambien probé en un array, y el error persiste @HeynerMartinez

Comment: cierto, perdon y bueno la verdad esta un poco complicado detectar el error, por que los casos que te mencionaba son los mas comunes que lanzan ese error, ya la ultima opcion  es que el find($id) te este retornando null (pero si la variable si o si la tienes que pasar por compact o key-value)

Answer (score 0):

Si haces solamente:

```
$someVariable = ['hello'];

view('some_view', $someVariable);
```

Lo que haces, es almacenarlo de esta manera:

```
"__data" => [
      ...
     0 => "hello"
]
```

Es por ello que debes utilizar `compact('someVariable')` o utilizar key-value `["key" => value]`, [entre otros](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#passing-data-to-views).

```
view('some_view', compact('someVariable'));
```

Para que hagas **debug** de lo que estás enviando, y cómo lo estás enviando, a tu vista, puedes utilizar lo siguiente:

```
{{ dd(get_defined_vars()) }}
```

Comment: Mira hice lo siguiente: return view('backend.products.detail', compact('detailData')); Y sigue persistiendo el mismo error.